# node, creating a stream object, that already has some streams internally piping

Tags: node.js, stream, pipe

I would like to create a stream Objetc in nodejs that is readable and writable that internally simply connects a number of stream objects, for allowing some level of abstraction for a project.

What would be the most elegant way to do this?

Here some code-sample to demonstrate what I try to do.

```
function main(transformerType) {
    var readStream = new ReadStream();
    var writeStream = new WriteStream();
    var transformerStream;

    if (transformerType === "a") {
        transformerStream = getATransformer();
    }
    else {
        transformerStream = getDefaultTransformer();
    }

    readStream.pipe(transformerStream).pipe(writeStream);
}

function getDefaultTransfromer() {
    return new DefaultTransformerStream();
}

function getATransformer() {
    var xStream = new LibraryXStream();
    var yStream = new LibraryYStream();
    xStream.pipe(yStream);

    // This next line won't work
    // I want to return a stream-object that has a function pipe which calls pipe from yStream
    // and when getting piped to will pipe into xStream
    // sort of a wrapper that has xStream and yStream already connected
    return xxx?;
}
```

Comment: if you return `yStream` from `getATransformer()`, it is already "connected` (piped in by `xStream`), since `a.pipe(b).pipe(c)` is equivalent to `a.pipe(b); b.pipe(c)`

Comment: Returning yStream won't do the trick for me. Yes xStream and yStream are already connected. But in the main-function readStream will then pipe to yStream the data won't flow through xStream. I tested that several times.

Answer (score 0):

I created the class TransformerWrapper which seems to solve the problem, at least in the test code below. Of course in that simple example all those streams could be connected together in one line. However, the goal is to find a method to return several connected streams that appear to be one readable/writable stream object to the calling function.

If somebody finds something smaller, better, I would appreciate that.

```
const stream = require("stream");

class TransformerWrapper extends stream.Transform {
    constructor (transformers) {
        super();
        var i = 1;

        this.firstTransformer = transformers[0];
        this.lastTransformer = transformers[transformers.length-1];

        this.lastTransformer.on("data", (chunk) => {
            this.push(chunk);
        });

        for (; i < transformers.length; i++) {
            transformers[i-1].pipe(transformers[i]);
        }
    }
    _write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        this.firstTransformer.write(chunk, encoding, callback);
    }
}

class TransformerA extends stream.Transform {
    _transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        this.push(chunk + '_A');
        callback();
    }   
}

class TransformerB extends stream.Transform {
    _transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        this.push(chunk + '_B');
        callback();
    }   
}

class Writer extends stream.Writable {
    _write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        console.log("writer", chunk.toString());
        callback();
    }   
}

var transformerA = new TransformerA();
var transformerB = new TransformerB();

var transformerWrapper = new TransformerWrapper([transformerA, transformerB]);
transformerWrapper.pipe(new Writer());
transformerWrapper.write("foo");
transformerWrapper.write("bar");
```